# A primitive root modulo $p^k$ is primitive modulo $p^{k+1}$,for $k\geq 2$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, problem-solving, primitive-roots

I am a graduate student of Mathematics.I am stuck with the following number theory problem:

Let $p$ be an odd prime.Prove that any primitive root modulo $p^k$ is a primitive root modulo $p^{k+1}$, for any $k\geq 2$.

I am a newcomer in number theory and I do not know how to proceed.Can please someone provide a solution to this problem?I have tried to proceed as follows:

Let $\alpha$ be a primitive root modulo $p^k$.

So,$(\alpha)=U(p^k)$

Which implies $\alpha^{\phi(p^k)}\equiv 1 (\mod p^k)\implies \alpha^{p^{k-1}(p-1)}\equiv 1(\mod p^k)$,thus $\alpha^{p^{k-1}(p-1)}=1+mp^k,$for some $m\in \mathbb Z$,so $\alpha^{{p^k}(p-1)}\equiv 1 (\mod p^{k+1})$.Then I got stuck.Can someone help me how to proceed?

Comment: The proof should be in any number theory textbook that discusses primitive roots. See Theorem 4 of [this post](https://exploringnumbertheory.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/primitive-roots-of-powers-of-odd-primes/), for example.

Comment: @GregMartin I did not find it in any book.Please help me to show that the order of $\alpha$ is $p^k(p-1)$ modulo $p^{k+1}$.

Comment: $\alpha^{p^{k-1}(p-1)}\equiv 1 (\mod p^k)$ and $\alpha^t\equiv 1 (\mod p^{k+1})$ where $t$ is the order of $\alpha$ modulo $p^{k+1}$,so $\alpha^t\equiv 1 (\mod p^k)$,ehnce $p^{k-1}(p-1)|t$.

Comment: Also $\alpha^{p^k(p-1)}\equiv 1 (\mod p^{k+1})\implies t|p^k(p-1)$,So,possible values of $t$ are $p^{k-1}(p-1)$ and $p^k(p-1)$.

Comment: Now how do I eliminate the first case and establish that the second one is actually the order.

Comment: By Euler's theorem for modulus $p^{k-1}$ we have $\alpha^{p^{k-2}(p-1)}\equiv 1 (\mod p^{k-1})$

Comment: This implies that $\alpha^{p^{k-2}(p-1)}=1+mp^{k-1}$ if $p|m$,then $\alpha^{p^{k-2}(p-1)}\equiv 1 (\mod p^k)$ but $\alpha $ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$,So $p\not|m$.

Comment: $\alpha^{p^{k-1}(p-1)}=(1+mp^{k-1})^p \equiv 1+mp^k(\mod p^{k+1})\not \equiv 1 (\mod p^{k+1})$